# Checking product stock availability in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I have following code that adds a simple notice about stock availability and shipping into product on shop/archive page, but in case when product stock quantity is 0 (is out of stock) notice is not showing up.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','show_stock_shop', 90 );

function show_stock_shop() {
    global $product;

    $regular = $product->regular_price;
    $sale = $product->sale_price;
//  $stock = the_field('stock-available');

    if ( $product->stock ) { // if manage stock is enabled 
        if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() > 0 && $regular >= 500 || $sale >= 500  ) { // in stock, free shipping
            echo '<div class="remaining text-center pt-2 pb-2">Skladom. <span class="doprava-zadarmo">Doprava zadarmo</span></div>';
        } elseif ( $product->get_stock_quantity() == 0 && $regular >= 500 || $sale >= 500 ) { // out of stock, free shipping
            echo '<div class="remaining text-center pt-2 pb-2"><s>(nie je skladom)</s>. <span class="doprava-zadarmo">Doprava zadarmo</span></div>';
        } elseif ( $product->get_stock_quantity() > 0 && $regular < 500 || $sale < 500 ) { // in stock, not free shipping
            echo '<div class="remaining text-center pt-2 pb-2">Skladom. <span class="doprava-zadarmo">Doprava zadarmo od 500 eur</span></div>';
        } elseif ( $product->get_stock_quantity() == 0 && $regular < 500 || $sale < 500 ) { // out of stock, not free shipping
            echo '<div class="remaining text-center pt-2 pb-2"><s>(nie je skladom)</s>. <span class="doprava-zadarmo">Doprava zadarmo od 500 eur</span></div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="remaining text-center pt-2 pb-2">Do ' . /*$stock .*/ ' dní</div>'; 
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your custom notice? The notice in the else?

Comment: I have added image. It outputs nothing as You can see, else not working...

Comment: And what notice do you mean? There are about 5 notices in your code.

Comment: The notices "out of stock" was wrong, now it's okay. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is outdated. Since Woocommerce 3, product properties can't be accessed directly and you should use [available `WC_Product` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html), like [`is_in_stock()` conditional method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_is_in_stock) to **check the product stock availability**.

Try the following simplified code version:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_loop_item_stock_notice', 90 );
function display_loop_item_stock_notice() {
    global $product;

    // For active product price: Free shipping || NO Free shipping
    $text = $product->get_price() >= 500 ? __("Doprava zadarmo") : __("Doprava zadarmo od 500 eur");

    // In stock
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) { 
        $text = __("Skladom.") . ' <span class="doprava-zadarmo">' . $text . '</span>';
    } 
    // Out of stock
    else {
        $text = '<s>(' . __("nie je skladom") . ')</s> <span class="doprava-zadarmo">' . $text . '</span>';
    }
    echo '<div class="remaining text-center pt-2 pb-2">' . $text . '</div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.